# Displaying the first text of the string/array in the texView

Tags: android

I have a code which changes the textview from Next and Back button. Before any button is pressed the textview is empty but i want to display the first element of the string. Here is my code.

```
private int _position = answers.length - 1;

String[] answers = { "info 1", "info 2", "info 3", "info 4", "info 5" };

getAnswerButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (_position > 0) {
            _position--;
        }
        else {
            _position = answers.length - 1;
        }
        answerLabel.setText(answers[_position]);

    }
});
```

Cant declare it in xml as it repeats the same information which disturbs the sequence.

Comment: you mean to say you want to display info 5 in textview initially right

Comment: @apk info 1 , i mean

Comment: then answerLabel.setText(answers[0]); add this line in oncreate after you initialize texview

Comment: Bro it works just like declaring it in the xml, i wanted to set the first element in the text view and if the button is clicked it should go to the second element in the string, right now the first element repeats twice, first it dsplays the first value and when the button is clicked than again it displays the first elemnt and so on

Comment: you need increment index first share code where you are incrementing index

Comment: @apk what index, i have shared the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put it into your code for initialise first answer,

```
answerLabel.setText(answers[0]);
```

ok. now i got what you mean and what you want. Please make question clearly.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int _position;

String[] answers = { "info 1", "info 2", "info 3", "info 4", "info 5" };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _position = 0;
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx)).setText(answers[_position]);
    findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (_position > 0) {
                _position--;
            }
            else {
                _position = answers.length - 1;
            }
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx)).setText(answers[_position]);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Bro it works just like declaring it in the xml, i wanted to set the first element in the text view and if the button is clicked it should go to the second element in the string, right now the first element repeats twice, first it dsplays the first value and when the button is clicked than again it displays the first elemnt and so on